# Where is the wordpress search results page?

Tags: wordpress, search

When I try to search from home page, I get the search results in the following URL
http://flintimm.cluster013.ovh.net/dev/property-search/?real_location=&real_type=any&real_town=Town&real_department=Department&real_status=any&real_bedroom=any&real_bathroom=any&min_price=any&max_price=any

I want to know where is the search results page located? I want to modify the search results.

Answer (score 0):

go to `wp-content\themes\your-theme-name` and look for `search.php`

hope will help you

Answer (score 0):

Building on Ram's answer, if your theme doesn't have a search.php file then index.php will be used to display results. See
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy